# Order of tests affecting number of Executed tests in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have encountered a Strange Behavior. The Order of directories in my test Suite is affecting the number of tests being Executed. If I define my suite like:

```
<testsuite name="functional">
    <directory>../src/Fsb/MrpBundle/Tests/Functional</directory>
    <directory>../src/Fsb/AppBundle/Tests</directory>
</testsuite>
```

then **32** tests are executed which equals the total number of tests in those directories if executed separately. However if I defined the suite like:

```
<testsuite name="functional">
    <directory>../src/Fsb/AppBundle/Tests</directory>
    <directory>../src/Fsb/MrpBundle/Tests/Functional</directory>
</testsuite>
```

then **tests** are executed.
 I am calling `phpunit` with `./bin/phpunit -c app/ -v --log-json phpunit-log.json --testsuite functional`.  any Idea what could be wrong?
I should note that there are **24** Tests in **MrpBundle** and **8** in **AppBundle**.
This is my complete `phpunit.xml.dist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="functional">
            <directory>../src/Fsb/MrpBundle/Tests/Functional</directory>
            <directory>../src/Fsb/AppBundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>

    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Is the same number of tests get executed if you remove the `<filter>...</filter>` part?

Comment: No, it's still different. Sorry for the extremely late reply.